# Paypal Form Checkout Group Items

Tags: paypal

when sending items via form to paypal.
For Example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="ball 1">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="15">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="ball 2">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="20">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_3" value="ball 3">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_3" value="11">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_4" value="shirt 1">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_4" value="50">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_5" value="shirt 2">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_5" value="80">
```

Is it on the resulting checkout page possible (with some hidden field) to group them visually?

[image]

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If there is two item is selected, it should be appear separately in PayPal checkout as I have listed below ;

[image]

Do you have trouble in selecting multiple item? For this sample, I've used Add To Cart Button for 2 different items.

Just a quick reminder that you can't use variable such item_name_n, amount_n ( n is any number ) without using the cart upload command.Have a look [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/).

Comment: Hi azlankasim, thanks for your reply. No my problem is not about adding multiple items. What I would be interested in is can I Group Items? In your example you have to "Carbonaras" is it possible to have something like a headline saying "pasta" where both are listed? Another one next to this could name "Pizza" where you have "Salami" and "Funghi" ;)

Comment: Ahh.. now I get it, sorry for the explanation before. Actually you do not have the control to the checkout page experience. You can't have the headline for the list of item choose during the checkout in the order summary..

Comment: Thanks azlankasim, well than I change my shopping cart and will send something like Pasta-2items to paypal ;) means I group them before cheers t book